# Jackson не распознается

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jackson

Хочу попробовать поработать с `Jackson` так как много слышал, вот открыл в `IntelliJ IDEA`, открыл вот этот туториал

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jackson/jackson_first_application.htm

и скопировал себе этот класс

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig;

public class JacksonTester {
public static void main(String args[]) {

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonString = "{\"name\":\"Mahesh\", \"age\":21}";

//map json to student

try {
  Student student = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Student.class);

  System.out.println(student);

  mapper.enable(SerializationConfig.Feature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
  jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(student);

  System.out.println(jsonString);
} catch (JsonParseException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (JsonMappingException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}

class Student {
private String name;
private int age;

public Student() {
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public int getAge() {
return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
this.age = age;
}

public String toString() {
return "Student [ name: " + name + ", age: " + age + " ]";
 }
}
```

Но import -ы не распознаются

Вот так выглядит структура проекта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как добавить эту зависимость ?

Comment: Ну, вообще можно настроить сборку проекта через gradle и подключать все зависимости как в AS - `compile 'либа'`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб У меня мало опыта работы с IntelliJ. Как настроить сборку через градл? И какую зависимость добавить для Jackson? Я скачал сам `.jar` файл, создал `libs` директорию и теперь я понимаю нужно как то указать, чтоб она использовалась ... В AS можно было нажать `add as a lib` и все... Как это сделать в `IntelliJ`?

Comment: Ну... Я всего раз в IntelliJ проект собирал простой и jar не пробовал там подключать. Попробуйте добавить в вопрос структуру проекта и какая система сборки используется. Если gradle, то, по идее, надо просто прописать как и в AS подключение все jar в папке libs

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Структуру добавил, а насчет системы сборки я так понимаю, что не градл так как нет тут этих файлов

Comment: Попробуйте вот как тут написано либу добавить в `classpath` http://stackoverflow.com/q/16742085/3212712

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Юрий это моя невнимательность была виновата. Просто та либа которую я добавлял она имеет расширение `.jar.zip` а соответственно нужно было ее распаковать и уже тогда становиться доступна функция `add as a lib` . Спасибо )